# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Number' and '1'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting an error when 
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Number' and '1'

```
buildQuerySpec() {
  return {
    PageSize: this.paging.PageCount,
    CurrentPage: this.paging.PageIndex + 1,
    MaxSize: '',
    Filters: this.filter,
    OrderFields: [],
    IsDescending: false
  };
}
```

what is wrong with

```
 CurrentPage: this.paging.PageIndex + 1,
```

pageIndex is number , no idea really.

Comment: Try adding the `unary` operator `+` like this => `CurrentPage: +this.paging.PageIndex + 1,` and see if it works.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Googling the error message leads you to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2031 which pretty much explains the reason why it does not work.

You can also have a look at the [Do's and Don'ts Section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html):

> **Number, String, Boolean, and Object**
>
> Don’t ever use the types `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, or `Object`. These
>   types refer to non-primitive boxed objects that are almost never used
>   appropriately in JavaScript code.
>
> ```
> /* WRONG */
> function reverse(s: String): String;
> ```
>
> Do use the types `number`, `string`, and `boolean`.
>
> ```
> /* OK */
> function reverse(s: string): string;
> ```

In other words, replace the type `Number` with `number`.

Comment: Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)
I have this problem in javascript?

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you can try adding the unary operator `+` like,

`CurrentPage: +this.paging.PageIndex + 1`

which will also work in your case.